# How to only join on numeric values

Tags: join, numeric

Right now I have:

```
select
    a.id
    b.colone
    b.coltwo
from tablea a
left join tableb b on b.id = a.id
```

I'm getting the "numeric value not recognized" error because one value from b.id is not numeric. How do I join results from tableb to tablea just omitting the non-numeric value/row? Or how else can I bypass this error? Using snowflake.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`TRY_TO_NUMBER()`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html):

```
select
    a.id
    b.colone
    b.coltwo
from tablea a
left join tableb b on TRY_TO_NUMBER(b.id) = a.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it.